# INSTALLING NETBEANS AND JDK WITHOUT ADMIN RIGHTS..?

Tags: java, netbeans, ide

I am a student of an army supervised University.In our computer labs it is impossible to install any softwares without administrator username and password .Though I have installed CODEBLOCKS IDE using a command by creating a batch file. Command is given below :

```
{set __COMPAT_LAYER=RunAsInvoker && start ----------}
```

But i can't install Netbeans along with JDK in PC.
So is there any ways to install them ..??

Comment: NetBeans have a zip distribution well hidden in the download page.

Comment: JDK can be unzipped to a directory too. Install on your personal computer with the setup (you have admin rights), then zip the installed files, and bring them to your uni. It works nicely for jdk 8 AFAIR.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen The zip distribution is hardly _"well hidden in the download page"_, at least for the current version of NetBeans: [Downloading Apache NetBeans 11.2](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb112/nb112.html).

Comment: @skomisa it used to be. Looks like this was reworked. Personally I’d prefer a zip, but the netbeans launcher needs to be told where to find a java distribution.

Comment: @ Jean-François Fabre are you sure that will work.....??